# How to automatically backup Cisco MDS 9000 switches

Tags: backup, cisco

Does anyone know if the Kiwi Cat Tool can backup the switch config from a Cisco MDS 9000 series switch?  I've used another TFTP tool to capture the config and copy it to a local directory, but it's a manual process.  I'm looking for a way to automate the backup.

Answer (score 2):

[RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) seems to be the de-facto tool for automated backups of Cisco devices. Along with backing up your configs, it can be set up to notify you if an unauthorized config change is made to one of your devices.